# Have Xcode open a given source file at specific line number (URL scheme?)?

Tags: xcode, xcode-instruments

I'm working on a custom log file viewer and would like to add a way to jump to a specific line in a source file in Xcode.

Is there a way to have Xcode reveal a given source file of the active project and jump to a given line number?

Maybe there is a custom URL scheme that I could use?

Instruments can do this (reveal a file in Xcode) so there must be a way for Instruments and Xcode to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched for the same thing and found [this discussion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/68964) on the Apple forums. The gist of it is that you can use the command line tool `xed` that ships with Xcode like so:

```
xed --line 42 Path/to/your/File.swift
```

Running `man xed` gives this description of the tool:

> The xed tool launches the Xcode application and opens the given documents, or opens a new untitled document, optionally with the contents of standard in.

It also mentions this option I used above:

> ```
>  -l, --line <number>
>           Selects the given line in the last file opened.
> ```

Comment: This doesn't work in Xcode 14.

Comment: This does work with Xcode 14.1 but opening to the line is very delayed. Please file feedback to Apple like I did! Hopefully they can speed things up.